# write recursive method in java & C#

Tags: java, c#, dereference

I want to convert this simple C# code to java :

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
return _destIndex.CompareTo(((DiffResultSpan)obj)._destIndex);
}
```

and my java code is :

```
public int compareTo(object obj)
{
return destIndex.compareTo(((DiffResultSpan)obj).destIndex);
}
```

but my code has error : "int can not be dereferenced".
I coded it in net-beans. Apparently it's true.but I don't know what should I do ?!!

thanks

oh thanks.i found it! int in java is not object.and I should convert it! for example :

```
new Integer(destIndex).compareTo...
```

Comment: Is `destIndex` an `int`?

Comment: It is unlikely that you really have this Java code. What is `object`? A superclass of `DiffResultSpan`? - There is no dereferencing of an int in the Java code snippet. Where is the line this error flagged?

Comment: Moreover, this is definitely not a *recursive* method.

Comment: Your code does not compile, your methods aren't recursive and it's unclear where your error is situated.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The lowercase "o" could be a typo, and `destIndex` is probably an `int`.

Comment: oh thanks.i found it! integer in java is not object.and I should convert it! for example : new Integer(destIndex).compareTo...          thank you...

Answer (score 0):

`int` in Java is a primitive type, meaning it has no methods or fields. If you want your compare method to compare two objects based on an `int`, the following should do fine:

```
return destIndex - ((DiffResultSpan)obj).destIndex;
```

If `destIndex` could be negative, there's a chance of integer overflow, so you would have to do:

```
int otherIndex = ((DiffResultSpan)obj).destIndex;
return destIndex < otherIndex ? -1 : (destIndex > otherIndex ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: oh thanks.i found it! integer in java is not object.and I should convert it! for example : new Integer(destIndex).compareTo...          thank you...

Comment: @faatemeh It's quite wasteful to box a primitive just to do a comparison. It's much more efficient to do the logic yourself, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: You're right. My goal was to just convert. Otherwise your code is correct.

Comment: @faatemeh Why would you want to "convert" it? You're exchanging performance for... nothing.

Comment: my teacher asked me!!! but if performance comes down that you said.I'll change it.thanks